# Why, for x=0, 'not x' is True and 'x' is False in Python?

Tags: python, integer, boolean-operations

I am stuck about `True`/`False` of `x` and `not x`,

for `x = 0` where `x` is `int`, in Python.

Why does `if not x` allow execution of the following statement and why not for `if x`?

Please give explanation.

Comment: `... of the following statement...` We seem to be missing you intended code. You can use the `edit` button to add it.

Answer (score 1):

from the python docs:

"By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method that returns zero, when called with the object. 1 Here are most of the built-in objects considered false:

- constants defined to be false: `None` and `False`.
- zero of any numeric type: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
- empty sequences and collections: `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

that is, zero is integer,

```
>>> type(0)
<class 'int'>
```

but has a False logical value, as '', (), []... and so on

Answer (score 1):

Because in python `0` is considered false, so when you write `(if x)` it will execute only when `x !=0` (so it will be evaluated as true).

Comment: Thanks for teaching me.  Quite helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

If statements don't execute their contents if their condition evaluates to a "false" value, like 0, an empty string, `False`, or an empty list/tuple.

Comment: Great help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Going to assume you mean

```
x = True
y = 0

if x:
  print('x is true')
if not y:
  print('your not sure why this prints')
```

This is because in Python, `0` evaluates to False.

Comment: It's a shame but I did not know '0 evaluates to False'.  Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

**`0` is a [subclass bool](https://jfine-python-classes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subclass-int.html), `False`, while any number that's not zero evaluates to `True`.**

```
x = 0
if not x
```

is like saying

```
x = 0
if x is False:
```

which the condition meets.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!  It makes it clear that I did not fully understand Boolean basics.

Comment: You know `if x:` means `if is True`, right?

Comment: I just learned it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a bit of Boolean review.
Everything in the world of python (and most of programming) boils down to be either True or False.
Lets take Integers, for example.
In python (and probably most languages) a value of 0 goes to False and everything else is True.
You can get the true/false value of just about anything in python by using the `bool` function. Try `bool(0)` or `bool(2)`.

Now, what `if` does is take an *expression* (basically just a Boolean value), and if it is True, executes the code block, and if it's False, skips it.

```py
x = 0
if x:
    print("This will never be printed because x is", x, "and it's Boolean value is", bool(x))
```

Now, what `not` does is take a Boolean value and make it the opposite. `not True` is `False`. `not False` is `True`. It does that however many times `not` is there, so `not not True` would be `True`.

```py
x = 0
if not x:
    print("This will print, because x is", 0, "the Boolean value of x is", bool(x), "and the not value of boolean x is", not bool(x))
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of Boolean basics.  I did try bool(0) and bool(2).  Really appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately: because the language definition says so.

Python has chosen to make almost any expression implicitly convertible to a boolean (True/False) value. The conversion is defined in the language.

For integer types, the conversion is that 0 is False, other values are True.

And, of course, if an expression *X* is False, then *not X* is True, by simple definition of the operator *not*.

Comment: Thank your for your kind explanation.  I didn't know 'For integer types, the conversion is that 0 if False'.  Great help!